Apache Ignite Cache FifoEvictionPolicy can not work
I used Apache Ignite V2.16.0 as a cache in Java head and wish that elements will be evicted after reaching the max size, but the elements still in the cache.
My codes are as below:
    CacheConfiguration<Long, Person> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<Long, Person>("myCache");
    cfg.setEagerTtl(false);
    cfg.setExpiryPolicyFactory(CreatedExpiryPolicy.factoryOf(new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 10)));
    cfg.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);
    cfg.setEvictionPolicyFactory(() -> new FifoEvictionPolicy<Long, Person>(10));

//        FifoEvictionPolicy<Integer, Person> evictionPlcy = new FifoEvictionPolicy<>();
//        evictionPlcy.setMaxSize(20);
//        cfg.setEvictionPolicy(evictionPlcy);

    IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
    igniteCfg.setCacheConfiguration(cfg);

    // Start a node.
    Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(igniteCfg);

    IgniteCache<Long, Person> personCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(cfg);
    for(long i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.id = i;
        person.salary = i;
        personCache.put(i, person);
    }
    
    Person p = personCache.get( 1L);
    if(p != null) {
      System.out.println("Key = " + p.id + ", Value = " + p.salary);
    }else {
        System.out.println("person is null");
    }

    IgniteBiPredicate<Long, Person> filter = new IgniteBiPredicate<Long, Person>() {
        @Override public boolean apply(Long key, Person p) {
            return key > 10 && key < 20;
        }
    };

    System.out.println("person query start -------");
    try (QueryCursor<Cache.Entry<Long, Person>> cursor = personCache.query(new ScanQuery<>(filter))) {
        for (Cache.Entry<Long, Person> entry : cursor)
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
    }
    System.out.println("person query end -------");

    Ignition.stop(ignite.name(), true);


The output is as below:
Key = 1, Value = 1.0
person query start -------
Key = 11, Value = Person [id=11, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=11.0, resume=null]
Key = 12, Value = Person [id=12, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=12.0, resume=null]
Key = 13, Value = Person [id=13, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=13.0, resume=null]
Key = 14, Value = Person [id=14, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=14.0, resume=null]
Key = 15, Value = Person [id=15, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=15.0, resume=null]
Key = 16, Value = Person [id=16, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=16.0, resume=null]
Key = 17, Value = Person [id=17, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=17.0, resume=null]
Key = 18, Value = Person [id=18, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=18.0, resume=null]
Key = 19, Value = Person [id=19, orgId=null, lastName=null, firstName=null, salary=19.0, resume=null]
person query end -------
[06:09:20] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:00.153]

Apache Ignite Cache FifoEvictionPolicy can work, the elements reached the FifoEvictionPolicy can be removed.

On-heap caching eviction does not remove entries from cache, only from the on-heap memory, see https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/on-heap-caching#configuring-eviction-policy
